# How to show that $e^{-x^2}$ is in the Schwartz class

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to show that $e^{-x^2}$ is in Schwartz class.

Now I want to show integral is infinite, this is simple. And I want to use the expansion to show the function and its derivatives decays. I don't know am I right, can anybody give me a full prove?

Comment: $f(x) = e^{-x^2}, f^{(k)}(x) =P_k(x) e^{-x^2}$ where $P_k$ is  a polynomial of degree $k$

Comment: @reuns Thanks, I get it. Then use the series to prove the  $x^k·e^{-x^2}$ is bounded.

Comment: No, then set $x = y^{1/2}$ and use that exponential grow faster than polynomials.